# SQL Sort by timestamp and group by id

Tags: php, sql

I use php, mysql and html together to show a table.
But I want to sort the items by timestamp and group the items with same id together.
Example:

Unsorted table:

```
timestamp       id      name        description

14:02           2       Hans        Is very nice!
12:01           3       Jürgen      Is very bad!
10:03           2       Hans        Again good.
11:08           6       Anna        BAD!
06:09           11      Peter       Good.
```

Right sorted table:

```
timestamp       id      name        description

06:09           11      Peter       Good.
10:03           2       Hans        Again good.
14:02           2       Hans        Is very nice!
11:08           6       Anna        BAD!
12:01           3       Jürgen      Is very bad!
```

Bad sorted table:

```
timestamp       id      name        description

06:09           11      Peter       Good.
10:03           2       Hans        Again good.
11:08           6       Anna        BAD!
12:01           3       Jürgen      Is very bad!
14:02           2       Hans        Is very nice!
```

I think there must be an INNER JOIN: First find the item with the oldest timestamp. Than look if there is another item with the same ID: If yes it must placed next to the item with the oldest timestamp.

Comment: What does your current query look like?

Comment: I want to use SELECT * ...

Comment: We're going to need something more than that. What you're saying is that you currently don't have any queries, is that correct? What have you tried already? What, exactly, isn't working for you?

Comment: plz add your query too

Comment: use this SELECT * FROM `table` GROUP BY `id` ORDER BY `timestamp` ASC

Comment: Please take a **very close look** at the `Right sorted table:` and think how you could possibly get the output in that order. ___Its not sorted on ID and it is not sorted on Timestamp___

Comment: SELECT * FROM TableName ORDER BY timestamp ,id no function!

Comment: I got 4 downvotes on my answer.  This is a new record!

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Just for interest sake _Not my downvote_

Comment: Doable with a combination of PHP and MySQL, but unlikely possible in a single MySQL query (not one that I can think of, anyway). Are you interested in an answer that also utilizes PHP?

Comment: @PatrickQ Go for it, I would love to see a solution just out of personal interest

Comment: It is only enought the MySQL SELECT. PHP is equal!

Answer (score 1):

If you're interested in an answer that uses *both* MySQL *and* PHP, then this will achieve what you want.

**MySQL**

```
SELECT `timestamp`, `id`, `name`, `description` FROM TableName ORDER BY `timestamp` DESC;
```

**PHP**

```
// execute your query and put the results into $dateSortedArray
// I am assuming you know how to do this

$outterArray = array();

// iterate through each row of the $dateSortedArray
foreach($dateSortedArray as $row)
{
    // this is where we're doing the 'sub ordering' part
    // I'm pre-pending 'id_' in the index so that it is string-based
    if(!isset($outterArray["id_".$row["id"]]))
    {
        // if we do not see this id in our result array yet,
        // add a new array with this row in it
        $outterArray["id_".$row["id"]] = array($row);

    }
    else
    {
        // if we have already see this id before,
        // add the current row to the array with this id-based index
        $outterArray["id_".$row["id"]][] = $row;
    }

}


// iterate through our result array
foreach($outterArray as $innerArray)
{
    foreach($innerArray as $innerRow)
    {
        // simply dump out each line, comma-seperated
        echo implode(",", $innerRow) . "\r\n";
    }
}
```

[Working Example](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/7213fc58fe04397cbc1d0fc5ab51ef5ec4ecf640)

Comment: Get my UV purely for effort and tanacity

Comment: @RiggsFolly Thanks :)

Answer (score -1):

Try This:

Subquery will return you temp column having NewTimeStamp which will same for same id column value.

```
SELECT
    X.timestamp,
    X.Id,
    X.name,
    X.description
FROM
(
    SELECT TMain.timestamp,TMain.id,TMain.name,TMain.description
    (
       CASE WHEN ((SELECT COUNT(1) FROM @tblTest T WHERE T.Id=TMain.Id))>0 
       THEN (SELECT TOP(1) timestamp  FROM @tblTest T WHERE T.Id=TMain.Id ORDER BY timestamp) 
       ELSE timestamp END 
    ) AS NewTimeStamp FROM @tblTest TMain
)X
ORDER BY X.NewTimeStamp,X.timestamp
```

Comment: Can i know reason for down vote?

Comment: Because this is wrong. The secondary sort column will only be used when the there are multiple occurrences of the same value in the primary sort column.

Comment: Yes this is wrong! I have test it!

Comment: Except he does not want the _timestamp : give you sort on timestamp by lower value to higher value._ and he does not want the _id : it will order id column_

Comment: Please check updated solution

Comment: Did you check if he was using SQLServer, he may be using MYSQL

Comment: Tag state SQL, and logic can also work in mysql